# Why does my Kubuntu boot so slow?

Tags: boot, kubuntu

It runs perfectly once booted but the booting process is very slow 
My specs are:

- 4 GB RAM
- 500 GB HDD
- 2.4 GHz Pentium quad core

Comment: Please run "systemd-analyze blame" in Terminal and edit your question and add some of the first lines.

Comment: To edit your question, please click [edit]. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, use [edit]. Editing tips are at https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code .